# Not create a Primary Key when typing in a form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I was wondering if there is a way for a form to not generate a Primary Key as soon as I start typing on a field (this is just in case I don't really want to insert)? Can it show what Primary Key will be generated when I do/only generate and insert in the table?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a Primary Key and a automatically generated number. It is true that Access proposes an autonumber field as a PK, but you can definitely switch it to a number or character field. Then, you will have to find a way to enter manually the PK value, or generate it through code(*), before inserting the record in the table.

(*) In case you are using numbers as PKs, the logic could be here to check the higher PK value already in the table (max()) and add 1 to it.

Comment: I know this is out of the way, but how would I go about in doing that. I'm not too familiar with Access. I'm so used to coding in C#

Comment: It is not that much an Access issue. Let's suppose that your table is Tbl, and that its id is Tbl_Id. An SQL query such as "SELECT MAX(Tbl_Id) FROM Tbl"  can be sent against the database and will return the last/max/higher value for Tbl_Id. You can then use this value to generate your own/next Id value.